# Google map integration with custom location

Tags: google-maps

I have added google map with custom location, how can I embed it into my website because that location is unable to search on google maps

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [**Google Maps Javascript API 3**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), and here's a real simple [**example**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple). It's easy to use so you can just copy and paste js and html code from the example and tweak it on your own website